# Multiplicar valor pegando só o primeiro carácter

Tags: javascript, ajax

Pessoal Preciso de uma Ajudo pois não tenho conhecimento de javascript

Nesse script a baixo ele faz calculos de acordo com um campo escolhido
ele funciona perfeito pra mim, mais o meu problema esta no dropdown.
esse dropdown ele faz uma multiplicação pelo value.

- value = "2"  ...    ok funciona perfeito

Mais é assim que preciso que o codigo aceite calculo

- value = "2-cd" ...   preciso que o javascript realize a multiplicação assim só pelo primeiro carácter

Preciso de uma alternativa que não modifique muito esse codigo.

Abaixo segue meu codigo como exemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".valores1").change(function() {
    var total = 1000;
    total += $('input[class="valores1"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
      return tot + Number(el.value);
    }, 0);
        
        
    var e = document.getElementById("valores2");
    var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    total=total+(itemSelecionado*20);
    $('#total1').val(total.toFixed(2));        
  });  
});
</script>
 

<script>
  function Mudarestado(el) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "block")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Duplica:<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')" name="direcao" value="1000" id="option_1"  />
Adciona:<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" name="bilingue" value="200" id="option_1"  />
<select id="valores2"   class="valores1 form-control" name="cadeirinha" >
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="2">Um Bebê Conforto</option>
    <option value="2-bc2">Dois Bebê Confortos</option>
    <option value="1-cd1">Uma Cadeirinha</option>
    <option value="2-cd2">Duas Cadeirinhas</option>
    <option value="1-as1">Uma Assento de elevação</option>
    <option value="2-as2">Dois Assento de elevação</option>
    <option value="2-ascd">Um Assento de elevação e Uma Cadeirinha</option>
    <option value="2-bccd">Um Bebe Conforto e Uma Cadeirinha</option>
    <option value="2-asbc">Um Assento de elevação e Um Bebe Conforto</option>
</select>  

<input type="text" size="5"  readonly="" name="valor" id="total1" value="1000.00"     />
```

Comment: Mas vai multiplicar por que valor ? Imaginando que escolhe `Duas cadeirinhas` multiplica `2` por quanto ? E se for `Dois Assento de elevação` ? Vai multiplicar `2` por quanto ? A estrutura que está a utilizar parece me confusa e propicia a erros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para retornar o primeiro digito use o método `substring()` que retorna um subconjunto de uma string entre um indice e outro, ou até o final da string.

**No seu caso** `itemSelecionado.substring(0,1)`

```
    var e = document.getElementById("valores2");
    var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    //aqui pega primeiro digito
    var primeiroDigito = (itemSelecionado.substring(0,1));
    total=total+(primeiroDigito*20);
    $('#total1').val(total.toFixed(2));
```

[Fonte - substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Perfeito.......